# Open a PDF file from C#.NET using Impersonate

Tags: c#, pdf, process, impersonation, process.start

I have a folder on the server containing pdf files(Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise). I have to open the folder with the authorized user account and display the pdf file in the browser. The user has full control permissions on the folder and is a member of the Administrator group.

Bellow code works from my local as it opens the pdf file from the folder located in the server in Adobe Reader. But on the server the process does not start(Adobe Reader does not open) and no exception occurs. Most of the forums say that turning off UAC will help, but I don't want to do it, because of security reasons.

How can I deal that issue? Please help.

```
try
{
    WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(@"user_name@DOMAIN");                
    WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;   

    try
    {
        ctx = wi.Impersonate();

        // Thread is now impersonating you can call the backend operations here...
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Verb = "open",                        
            FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mobil"] + "\\" + prmSicilNo + "_" + prmPeriod.ToString("yyyyMM") + ".pdf",                                            
        };

        p.Start();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msj = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        ctx.Undo();
    }                             

    return msj;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{        
    return msj + "Error: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your .exe with Run as Adminstrator on the server.If it works properly then add the below code:

```
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Chintan Udeshi` Thank you for you quick answer. I can run the **AcroRd32.exe** by `Run as Administrator` but when I tried with `runas` I got the error which says; **"No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"**.

I also tried to place absolute Acrobat Reader Path, but it still didn't work. Any idea?

```
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe")
{
   CreateNoWindow = true,
   Verb = "runas",                        
   FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mobil"] + "\\" + prmSicilNo + "_" + prmPeriod.ToString("yyyyMM") + ".pdf", // "c:\\pdf\\",                                            
};
```